# jquery mobile page dialog: tell dialog close from opening a new dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, hide

Open page as dialog. For example,

```
page1 -> page2(dialog) -> page3(dialog).
```

when opening a dialog, a dialog page is created in DOM by ajax.

```
   <div data-role="page" id="dialog1">
       ....
   </div>

   $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#dialog1", { role: "dialog" } );
```

Opening dialog using page by ajax: works.

when a dialog closes, a code is executed to remove the page dialog element from DOM.

PageContainer hide event is registered as:

```
$( document).on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.prevPage) {
       ui.prevPage.remove();
    }

});
```

Issue: when a page dialog close, the ui.prevPage is not defined in the code above. ui.nextPage is correctly defined to point to the next page. How to catch event in order to remove the DOM element of a hidden page.

I tried navigation between two existing pages, both ui.prevPage and ui.nextPage are defined for pagecontainerhide event. what is the difference for hiding pages created by ajax (add page elements to DOM).

Note that: pagecontainerhide event can not be bound to page. pagehide event that is bound to page is deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have two dialogs within same document, you want to completely remove first dialog from DOM upon opening second dialog?

Comment: No. the second dialog is on the top of the first dialog. When closing the second dialog, remove it from DOM, and the first dialog is visible. Only the dialog on the top can be removed, like modal dialog. Thanks.

Comment: You cant have two active dialogs or popups at the same time.

Comment: the dialogs are not popups. they are pages in dialog style. So when the second dialog is shown, the first dialog underneath is hidden.

Comment: When you have an active dialog (dialog1) and then navigate to another one (dialog2), dialog1 is closed and not visible anymore. You want to go back to dialog1 upon closing dialog2?

Comment: yes. when dialog2 is closed, dialog1 will be visible. multiple-level modal dialogs. This is a workaround of jquerymobile unsupported chained popups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64746/discussion-between-omar-and-dave).